# Icenium / Phonegap Build - how do they create IOS ipa?

Tags: windows, cordova, ipa, icenium

I'm currious to know how e.g. Telerik Icenium / Phonegap Build creates IOS ipa files?
Do they use physical mac's for this task or how do they come about this?

Or rephrased: Can I in any way create Cordova ipa files on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an actual Mac, just Mac OSX. If you don't feel like buying a mac than you can get a hold of the image of Mac OSX and install it onto your PC using Virtual Machine software. I use VMWare to run MacOSX from my Windows 7 x64 machine.

VM's are a great way to go, the driers can take a bit to setup, but once everything is working it's perfect.

VM's even support ethernet so from within the VM you can browse the web, download mac apps.

Install things like XCode or GameSalad. I suggest researching how to use Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm part of Icenium team). Yes, we're using physical Mac machine to build your app for iOS.